# Git .DS_Store file removal fails

Tags: git

In my git repo, I run

`find . -name .DS_Store -print0`

It shows a list of nested .DS_Store files.  However, when I run:

`find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch`

It fails to remove the files.

Advice?

Comment: It sounds like they're already not in the Git repository in the first place. Remember, your work-tree is not in the repository either: the OS creates its own files in your work-tree, after `git checkout` copies committed (in-repository) files to your work-tree. On MacOS, the Finder creates those `.DS_Store` files. These files are not in Git unless and until you tell Git to put them into a new commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the `.DS_Store` folders on MacOS. So you can remove the `.DS_Store` files on git repository via on the following command.

```
echo .DS_Store >> .gitignore
git rm -f .DS_Store
```

Comment: ```fatal: pathspec '.DS_Store' did not match any files```